# ¿Cómo mostrar el primer y ultimo codigo de cada registro agrupado?

Tags: mysql, sql

Primero que nada les muestro mis dos tablas relacionadas (Les envio imagen porque no se como colocarlo como codigo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que entiendan la lógica de estas dos tablas, es una base de datos para hacer inventario, hay varias categorías, una de ellas es los bienes capitalizables, por lo que utilizo un detalle inventario para poder traer todas las categorías hacia una sola tabla.

A veces se ingresan uno o mas registros, es decir, si ingresan 3 laptops iguales, se coloca la misma descripción y se digita la cantidad en un solo formulario (los datos ingresan una vez y el sistema crea 3 registros diferentes), entonces el sistema insertará 3 registros en la base de datos tanto en la tabla detalleInventario como en la tabla bienesCapitalizables, y se coloca un numero de agrupación en la tabla detalle inventario, por ejemplo `C1` (ese código se insertará en las 3 laptops) y así sucesivamente. Se ingrese uno o varios registros, siempre tendrá un numero de agrupación.

Les muestro los datos que tienen las tablas (solo los datos necesarios para mi problema):

DetalleInventario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

BienesCapitalizables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les explico que es lo que necesito:

Quiero que en una consulta mysql me muestre todos los registros agrupados por el codigo de agrupación que yo mismo genero y que inserto en el campo que pueden ver en la tabla, y de cada registro agrupado quisiera obtener 3 cosas:

1. Cantidad
2. El primer codigo registrado de ese grupo
3. El ultimo codigo registrado de ese grupo

Ahora les muestro que es lo que he intentado para obtener esos valores:

```
    SELECT 
        di.agrupacion,
        (SELECT COUNT(agrupacion) FROM detalleInventario WHERE agrupacion=di.agrupacion) as cantidad,
        (SELECT MIN(bcc.codigoNuevo) FROM bienesCapitalizables bcc INNER JOIN 
        detalleInventario dii WHERE dii.agrupacion=di.agrupacion) as codMin,
        (SELECT MAX(bcc.codigoNuevo) FROM bienesCapitalizables bcc INNER JOIN 
        detalleInventario dii WHERE dii.agrupacion=di.agrupacion) as codMax 
    FROM bienesCapitalizables bc                        
    INNER JOIN detalleInventario di ON bc.codDetalleInventario=di.idDetalleInventario
    WHERE bc.active=1
    GROUP BY di.agrupacion
```

Y lo que obtengo de esa consulta es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la cantidad es correcta, ya que tengo varios registros, pero el primer y ultimo codigo se repiten en todos, cuando deberia darme el primer y ultimo codigo de cada agrupación

¿Como puedo hacerlo? Les agradecería mucho su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es muy sencilla, me estaba complicando cuando solo debi hacer esto:

```
SELECT
di.agrupacion,
MAX(bc.codigoNuevo) as codMax,
MIN(bc.codigoNuevo) as codMin,
(SELECT COUNT(agrupacion) FROM detalleInventario WHERE agrupacion=di.agrupacion) as cantidad
                    FROM bienesCapitalizables bc
                    INNER JOIN detalleInventario di ON bc.codDetalleInventario=di.idDetalleInventario
                    WHERE bc.active=1
                    GROUP BY di.agrupacion
```